Virtuemart character counter for meta boxes (on admin page; meta title, meta description etc.)
How can I put a character counter in the meta boxes (meta title, meta description) on the Virtuemart admin product adding page?
(Only visible on admin page)
or
Can I get the file path of the product editing page back-end the site?
Best regards
For example, I couldn't find where to add this:
$simple = "$meta-title-box";
echo strlen($simple);
